# How to get current uploading speed when live stream with RTMP

Tags: actionscript-3, rtmp, netstream

I want to create an application to live stream with RTMP.
And I use **NetStream.publish** to live stream.

When I set **NetStream.bufferTime=0 (default value)**, I can create a Timer to get **NetStream.info.currentBytesPerSecond** as uploading speed.

But if I set  **NetStream.bufferTime= 1(Some value larger then 0)** ,  **NetStream.info.currentBytesPerSecond** becomes 0 and never change~

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Your net connection has a method called on it's client named `onBWDone`, the first parameter passed to that function is the bandwidth in kbps I believe.   Though i don't recall if that number is up/down stream

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Thanks for comment. I try adding a handler `onBWDone`,but the length of parameters is 0 and only invoked once. In fact I need to create a Timer to get current speed every second, maybe only can get through it with the `NetStream`.